# Django REST error returning a list of objects

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django REST framework in order to implement a game server for an android game. I have written a class, that is derived from GenericAPIView to handle a specific Http Post request. I want the request to return a list of some objects, that were previously queried from the database.

My code looks like this:

```
class NewGameView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class=NewGameRequestSerializer
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = NewGameRequestSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            req=serializer.save()

            mygamedata=...; # request game data objects

            serializer = MyGameDataSerializer(mygamedata, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I access this view via curl, everything works as expected. However, when I submit using the Django generated "browsable api" form, I am receiving a
`'ListSerializer' object is not iterable`
error during "template rendering". If I derive my class from APIView instead, the error does not occur, but Django will not display the forms anymore (for whatever reason).

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: there is no `ListSerializer` variable in your code. can you provide further code?

Comment: The `ListSerializer` class is nothing I have written. It is part of the Django REST framework. My `MyGameDataSerializer` is derived from `serializers.ModelSerializer`. I believe that passing many=True automatically makes it use this ListSerializer in some way. I am unsure about the exact internals though (I am fairly new to Django REST).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return a dictionary with the data you need.

```
class NewGameView(GenericAPIView):
serializer_class=NewGameRequestSerializer
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = NewGameRequestSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        req=serializer.save()

        mygamedata=...; # request game data objects

        data = {'game_name': mygame_object.name}
        return Response(data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Well I did not use the ModelViewSet class, because my API interface does not really have a 1:1 correspondence to the database structure. My NewGameRequest class for example does not correspond to any model. Nevertheless, I did try what you said, and after also changing the url pattern to: `url(r'^new_game/', views.NewGameView.as_view({'post': 'post'}))` it showed the exact same problem as it did before.

Comment: @Dtag so you are not trying to create a new database entry with the post?

Comment: I am generating new database entries with that post, but it does not have a 1:1 correspondence of what is being posted. For example the post might be {"playername":"foo"}, which matches my "NewGameRequest" object. Based on that, I might add a "Game" object to the database, that contains the player as a foreign key, but also other game specific information, that was not contained in the post request.

Comment: Change your url to `url(r'^new_game/',views.NewGameView.as_view())`

Comment: That's what it was like before. When using ModelViewSet as the basis class, as you proposed, this results in the error `The 'actions' argument must be provided when calling '.as_view()' on a ViewSet. For example .as_view({'get': 'list'})`

Comment: The error occurs on this line serializer = MyGameDataSerializer(mygamedata, many=True), if you remove the many=True it should fix the issue, you can also just return a dictionary with all the data

Comment: Hm i have tried it, but it results in `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'game_name' on serializer 'MyGameDataSerializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'QuerySet' instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'game_name'.`. This makes sense to me, since the MyGameDataSerializer believes it is supposed to serialize a MyGameData objects, not lists or sets of those objects, unless many=True.

Comment: The issue is that the browsable api can't render the response so id you return data={'name': 'GameData'} as the response you wont get the error, I'll update my answer to show you what I meant

Comment: Ahaa yes. `data = {'game_name': mygame_object.name}` this had to be `data = {'game_name': mygamedata}`. But it worked otherwise :). Thank you. As I understand it, the problem appears to be that a list of objects alone, without a "key",  can not be displayed or something.